# While loop does not print the requested amount of lines

Tags: c, while-loop

still very new to C and trying to understand this better. The instruction is to input a certain number of lines using a while loop, but mine appears to only print a total of 10 lines never what I have instructed to print. What am I missing for it to print only what I input?

```
 int numLines;
printf("Enter lines: ");
scanf("%d", &numLines);
aroundTheWorld(numLines);

    //First line
    printf("Around the world,\n");
    //Repeating lines  
    while(numLines < 10)
    {
    printf("around the world,\n");
    numLines++;   
    }
    // applies a full stop
    printf("around the world.\n");

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. That is not enough to see what is wrong. What is `numLines`? How is it defined, what value does it hold before you reach the loop?

Comment: "to input a certain number" Where do you have any input?

Comment: Please edit the question to add missing parts. Code in comments is basically unreadable.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone and edited.

Comment: Please provide some code that is actually compileable. What is `aroundTheWorld()` Please read [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit the question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this condition in the while statement with the magic number 10

```
while(numLines < 10)
```

write for example

```
while ( 0 < numLines-- )
{
    printf("around the world,\n");
}
```